# Editing a question for a small edit after having a best answer

Tags: discussion, editing

Sometimes, when I ask a question and I'm not sure how to word it, as is often the reason why I must ask the community in the first place, I miss some information or other important details.  This is the result of not really knowing what I was looking for.

An example could be [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87460/write-a-parabolic-equation-in-kinematics/87463?noredirect=1#87463), in which I needed a way to turn my kinematic details into a parabolic equation.  In short, I made a mistake in quoting the standard form and didn't notice it until the answerer kindly pointed it out.

However, I have already edited the question once and I have a best answer.  I know about editing old questions and I get the feeling that the community doesn't much care if I elaborate upon the question, but this would be a minor edit to correct some misinformation.  It would bump the question to the main page again (for what I know) and inadvertently *take away* from other questions, if nothing else.  So, even if the user base doesn't mind seeing the same question again for a frivolous edit, it still pushes more relevant questions down.

**My question is, should I make this small edit or not?**
If I don't, the question will have misinformation (probably not harmful, however).
If I do, the question will be bumped to the main page and affect more recent questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Occasional minor edits are fine. Don't worry about bumping your question to the front page; there's nothing wrong with that.

What we do frown on is making a *lot* of minor edits, especially over a short period, or making trivial edits that don't improve the quality of the question at all.

Comment: And, as a corollary, if you're editing, try to do all that needs doing!